# Google custom search engine API country based result not showing

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I was working with Google customer search engine api and there I got a big mismatch. When I go this page https://google.com/search?q=carob&pws=0&nord=1&hl=de&gl=DE

it gives me bellow results.

```
[
    {'link': 'https://eatsmarter.de/ernaehrung/news/carob'},
    {'link': 'https://www.lebensfreude-aktuell.de/carob-schokoladenersatz/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.rapunzel.de/bio-produkt-carobpulver--1420210.html'},
    {'link': 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannisbrotbaum'},
    {'link': 'https://utopia.de/ratgeber/carob-eine-alternative-zu-kakao/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.rundumgesund.de/ernaehrung/lebensmittel/carob-pulver-wirkung/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.silkeleopold.de/was-ist-eigentlich-carob-und-was-macht-man-damit/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/Biovegan-Bio-Carob-200/dp/B008B76INC'},
    {'link': 'https://www.miomente.de/entdeckermagazin/carob-pulver-die-gesunde-kakao-alternative/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.regenbogenkreis.de/blog/gesundheit-und-ernaehrung/blog-carob-ein-wertvolles-lebensmittel-mit-besonderen-gesundheitsfoerdernden-eigenschaften-regenbogenkreis'}
]
```

**I got this result get from python requests and bs4 and this is actual result. I tried from many browser. The results are same**

But when I search the same keyword using api call, it gives results like this.

```
[
    {'link': 'https://eatsmarter.de/ernaehrung/news/carob'},
    {'link': 'https://www.lebensfreude-aktuell.de/carob-schokoladenersatz/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.rapunzel.de/bio-produkt-carobpulver--1420210.html'},
    {'link': 'https://www.returningfromgermany.de/programmes/carob-armenia'},
    {'link': 'https://utopia.de/ratgeber/carob-eine-alternative-zu-kakao/'},
    {'link': 'https://www.amazon.de/Biovegan-Bio-Carob-200/dp/B008B76INC'},
    {'link': 'https://www.pureraw.de/Carob-Pulver-Bio-Roh'},
    {'link': 'https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/carob.html'},
    {'link': 'https://schrotundkorn.de/rezepte/carob-balls'},
    {'link': 'https://www.rundumgesund.de/ernaehrung/lebensmittel/carob-pulver-wirkung/'}
]
```

See there are some difference in them.

my api call

```
resource = build('customsearch', 'v1', developerKey=search_api_key).cse()
result = resource.list(q=keyword, cx=search_cx, start=1, gl='de', lr='lang_de', hl='de', cr="countryDE").execute()
```

What other keyword should I pass to list() in order to get exact same result like first one.

Thanks